# How to sort spreadsheet based on partial matches

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet of imported broken links as shown in screenshot below. I need to get rid of any rows where the domain names in column A and B are the same (such as in row 3 in the screenshot) and keep any rows where they are different (such as in row 1 in the screenshot).

The problem I'm having is that when the domains are the same, the rest of the URL is different so I can't sort based on the exact match. How would I sort based on the partial match of just the domain so I can get rid of domain matches?

[image]

Comment: **What character string would you like to use to define the end of the domain ?**

Comment: That's part of the problem because it can be ".com", ".ac.uk", ".edu" and many more so I'd need to cover all possibilities. There's a forwards slash / at the end of every domain. Maybe that could be used somehow? It's always going to be the 3rd forward slash in the URL (after http://)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last comment solved the problem!............use a "helper" column to perform the sort......start with:

**=MID(A1,1,FIND("/",A1,8)-1)**   and copy down

The above formula should give you the domain part of the URL.

Since the **FIND** locates the third "/"

Comment: Thanks, works great for column A, but column B is a bit different. The cells have have 8 spaces before the start of the link. How could I apply this to column B? Thanks again

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Thanks very much!